# How to hide part of a WPF control conditionally?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, controls, behavior

I have a control in an assembly that I can't change that is very similar to the .NET `DateTimePicker`.  I want to hide the time picker portion of that control when a certain condition is met (Property value on my ViewModel). The control looks like this:

```
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_DatePicker", Type = typeof (DatePicker))]
[TemplatePart(Name = "PART_TimePicker", Type = typeof (TimePicker))]
public class MyDateTimePicker : Control    {/*...*/}
```

This answer shows a nice way to always hide a PART of a control, but I want to do it dynamically:

[How to hide a part of a WPF control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751217/how-to-hide-a-part-of-a-wpf-control)

I imagine there are a few ways to do this. What I want is something minimal (like in the linked question's answer) as well as something that doesn't violate MVVM.  `System.Interactivity` behaviors and triggers are fair game.

Comment: Couldn't you do a data trigger with the template part behavior?

Comment: I could do the binding to the ViewModel, but I think you're suggesting pretty much what the current answer is suggesting, and I don't know how to hide the one part of the control that way.

Comment: Not quite, I'm suggesting you follow the answer listed in the related question you linked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4754266/7116

Comment: Interesting.  How would I get that trigger to run when a property changes on the ViewModel instead of on Loaded like in the example?

Comment: Absolutely forget MVVM.  This is UI work.

Comment: Okay, fine.  Suppose I drop MVVM.  Lets say I want to change the visibility based on the IsSelected property of a radio button, how do I point it to that other object?  (sorry, I'm fairly new to System.Interactivity)

Comment: @JoeB: I avoid System.Interactivity as it is not part of the WPF stack  (its from Expression Studio).  I would simply extend the class and be done.  Added an answer.

Comment: Appreciated.  I'll check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a new control extending the previous one

```
public sealed class MySuperiorDateTimePicker : MyDateTimePicker 
{
    //....
```

Add a DependencyProperty that you can bind to your ViewModel's state

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty HideItProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
        "HideIt",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(MySuperiorDateTimePicker ),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(false, HideItPropertyChanged));
//snip property impl
```

Wait for the property to change, then hide your UI

```
private static void HideItPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d,
    DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    (d as MySuperiorDateTimePicker).OnHideItChanged((bool)e.OldValue, 
        (bool)e.NewValue);
}

private void OnHideItChanged(bool oldValue, bool newValue)
{
    if(BusyTemplate == null)
        return;
    FindTimePicker().Visibility = newValue ? Visibility.Visible : 
        Visibility.Collapsed;
}

private UIElement FindTimePicker()
{
    //snip null checks
    return GetTemplateChild("PART_TimePicker") as UIElement;
}
```

Be careful with `FindTimePicker` as your DP might change before the control is loaded, and `GetTemplateChild` will return null.  The usual thing to do is, in `OnHideItChanged`, if `GetTemplateChild` returns *null* use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to re-run the event handler later on (`ApplicationIdle` or earlier).

When you find yourself saying "How can I do UI work using MVVM" stop and rethink your true goals.  MVVM != no codebehind, no custom controls, etc.

Comment: Hi Will.  First off, I don't think this breaks MVVM.  I agree, this is strictly UI work, what I specifically didn't want to do was have any reference between my VM and controls which this avoids.

I originally tried to inherit like this, simply overriding the template method, which didn't work.  I do have faith in this solution, but I found an easier way for me, so I'm going to go with what works.  I will detail my answer in another "Answer", and give you the points for helping.  Thank you!

Comment: @JoeB: np.  If your easier way is better, then select it as the accepted answer!

Comment: Your answer is more reusable, mine is more practical.  Mine also requires Blend.

Tell you what, I'll check back in a couple weeks and if mine has more votes I'll change it.  Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to hide it with the help of a DataTrigger defined in the datatemplate, so that when a certain value in the datacontext of the control is set to true/false then you will hide/show the part.

A quick search and i found some links that you might find useful:
http://zamjad.wordpress.com/2010/06/22/conditionally-hide-controls-from-data-template/
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/ae2dbfb7-5dd6-4352-bfa1-53634289329d/

Comment: I'm not sure how I would hide the PART_TimePicker doing it this way, or if it's even possible.

Comment: just follow the example in the first link. Create a DataTrigger for the DataTemplate and tie it to a  property you set behind in the datacontext.

Comment: I understand how to use a DataTrigger to change visibility on something like a textbox.  This is a control with multiple parts.  Look at the link I put in the question, and at the solution, if what you're suggesting worked in a case like this I think they would have just done it that way.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to edit the style of the control.  Using Blend, I edited a copy of the style of the DateTimePicker, and added a binding to Visibility of the TimePicker that looks at my VM and converts the value of the enumeration.